# how to stop command execution in command prompt windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-preview

in recent release of windows 10 command prompt microsoft have placed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> ,in older versions we used to stop command prompt execution by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

In recent release of windows 10 command prompt cant stop the execution..any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CTRL+C` will send a break (stop execution) when no text is selected. Try it ;-)

[Reference](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)

Comment: but for e.g take a traceroute press ctrl c the command execution doesnt stop..

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 Even if you press `CTRL+C` twice?

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 you have to wait for all threads to terminate and all hardware calls to finish. Traceroute can't just close all hardware connections, it has to wait until all devices have finished their job (in this case only the network adapter/controller)

Comment: @GiantTree Hmm, in all my tests `tracert` terminates immediately upon `CTRL+C`. Interesting...

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 Are you using Windows `tracert` command, or are you doing a traceroute via the router itself (e.g. using telnet)?

Comment: @misha256 for me as well, but maybe there is some blocking hardware call going on (I imagine metered connections because they have high latency sometimes).

Comment: Another command to break is `CTRL + break/pause`. It breaks in a different way than `CTRL + C` does, but it might work too.

Comment: confirmed, ctrl+c breaks the tracert command, build 10162

Answer (score 5):

I had the same thing happening with Ctrl+C not stopping the Tracert process. However Ctrl+Pause/Break did.

This was on Windows 10 build 1709 with updates current as of 06-27-2018. I suspect whatever is going on will be machine specific for some odd reason.

Comment: This solved it for me in Anaconda Prompt. In normal CMD on win10, ctrl+c worked, but there I had to use Ctrl+Break. I can confirm that it is machine dependent - it does not happen on my laptop with win10

Comment: And what is Pause/Break button?? Where can I find it on a non-English keyboard?

Comment: Oh, I got it. It's the Shift key on the right hand side of my hp laptop keyboard!! I have already found out from [HP Community Forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/Break-Key/td-p/413817) that for hp laptops, you can press "fn" key and then the Shift. So, the correct combination which worked for me on windows 10 was: `Control + fn+Shift(right-hand side)`

Answer (score 2):

best way seems (thanks to @LPChip):

`CTRL+ Break(pause)`

Comment: That key no longer exists on the new ThinkPad keyboard layout :(

Comment: It worked for me pressing `CTRL + (fn + right-hand-side shift)` on my hp laptop with windos 10.

Answer (score -1):

we can use "EXIT" to close the CMD :)